# Is it safe to install Kubuntu-desktop in 11.10?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Has anyone noticed issues during and/or after the installation of KDE desktop?

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

I already have Gnome Shell along with Unity but want to add KDE for testing purposes. I heard somewhere that in Ubuntu 11.10, it does not go smoothly.

Comment: Heard it from who/ where? it is fine.

Comment: The only problem I've ever had was with the oxygen gtk theme engine. But usually if everything got really weird a restart would fix things.

Comment: Ok Great! I heard it from a System Engineer, a former colleague! Anyway! Thanks for your confirmations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you heard/read but it works just fine. Kubuntu is built on the same base as Ubuntu, uses the same libraries etc, just that KDE and it's related libraries+programs provide the desktop environment.

In fact, I have it installed (Kubuntu-desktop) on two systems with no problems...

Comment: Just a question but how does the text appear in other DEs other than KDEs?